# vlc keeps prompting for password for nginx authentication

Tags: nginx, encryption, https, vlc

I have configured a video stream using picam on a raspberry pi and mapped it through nginx. I have also encrypted the link with basic authentication like so;

```
  location /hls/ {
    root /run/shm;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
```

When I view through a browser it prompts once for the password and then I can watch the video. If I try to view it through VLC I will be prompted multiple times for the password forever and never see the video.

Here is how I run picam;

```
sudo bash /home/pi/make_dirs.sh

sudo mkdir /run/shm/hls
sudo cp /home/pi/enc.key /run/shm/hls

sudo /home/pi/picam/picam -o /run/shm/hls --hlsenc --hlsenckeyuri enc.key   --hlsenckey <my encryption key>   --hlsenciv <my encryption> --fps 8 --videobitrate 250000 --width 640 --height 480 --time --noaudio > /var/log/picam.log 2&>1
```

I'm following the tutorial:
https://kamranicus.com/guides/raspberry-pi-3-baby-monitor which doesn't fully get into the encryption part.

Comment: version 3.x reuses credentials between requests

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm not getting prompted multiple times, but I am having an issue viewing the stream after enabling the basic authentication.

Comment: I still have this problem and I'm currently just viewing the feed within a browser. Would be nice to fix this one day.